# Increment property name, when adding to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, list, if-statement, foreach, observablecollection

I have a collection of components, where the component name is unique for each one of them. When the user adds a new component to this collection, the component name should increment by 1, depending on the number of already existing components. When the user removes a component, the component name given to a newly added component should still be unique.

Right now I am looping through the components in the collection, to get the total amount of each, and increment the counter for every one that is equal to the component to be added.

```
private void OnComponentAdded()
        {
            if (SelectedComponent != null)
            {
                var numberOfDuplicates = 0;
                foreach (var item in ComponentsForEquipment)
                {
                    if (item.ComponentId == SelectedComponent.ComponentId)
                    {
                        numberOfDuplicates++;
                    }
                }
                numberOfDuplicates++;
                SelectedComponent.ComponentName = SelectedComponent.ComponentType + numberOfDuplicates.ToString();

                var match = ComponentsForEquipment.Where(c => c.ComponentName == SelectedComponent.ComponentName).SingleOrDefault(); //componentname already exists
                if (match == null)
                {
                    ComponentsForEquipment.Add(SelectedComponent);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a component before adding.", "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }

        }
```

But if the user removes a component and then adds it again, the component name will not be unique. Therefore I added the if statement to check for a match by component name. The problem is if the user removes a previously added component, the new name generated will not be unique.

Here is an example of duplicate components in the collection:
[image]

So if there are 3 duplicate components in the collection, the 4th added one should have a ComponentName with "4" attached to the end to ensure the name is unique from the rest.

Comment: Check collection first, maybe you never get into loop. Debugging check if statement because your counter is 1 so that's mean counter is increment only once after foreach loop.

Comment: Is it an option to have a counter representing the next ID, and increment it whenever an item is added? That means you will never get duplicates (but you may get 'gaps' in IDs if an item is removed).

Answer (score 0):

Generally your code works but always in one direction when you keep adding elements in your collection. The problem is what happen when you remove some element? In that case your counter is useless but still he doing good, so that means you need to change whole logic.

In database we have **auto increment id** but even then you will never see that **id** will fill gaps maked by removing rows. That counter will always go straight forward. You need to implement something like that or you need to make helper method who will iterate thought components with same name and decrement number in they names (last char in names).

As you can see this solution isn't good in many ways (OOP, solid and clean code principles) so i advice to refactor your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because your requirements contradict each other. You state that an assigned names for the new component should:
1) be something + number of already existing components
2) be unique

As you say, it is pretty easy to imagine a situation when you can't have both of them at the same time. Like in your example you should either name your newly added component 'ComponentName 4' (which is not unique) or come up with some unique name, but that will not be an amount of already existing items.

So, your requirements can't be met. Not because of poor algorithms or wrong  ID generation strategy or whatever, that's just because the requirements are not consistent. It will not help if you refactored your solution to the core: that's the requirements where the problem is, not the solution.

You have to decide which one is less important for you and either allow non-unique names or do not require newly added components to be named after the amount of already existing ones. Or, maybe, come up with some absolutely different naming strategy.